# Selected Item for SelectListItem

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to set the "Selected Item" in my Html.DropDownListFor

My controller looks like this:

```
HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["MyCookie"];
if (cookie != null)
{
    model.cookieValues = new cookieValues();
    model.cookieValues.formSelected = cookie.Values.Get("FormSelected");
}

model.formGroups = new List<SIMSClient.FormGroup>();
model.formGroups = SIMSClient.ClientFunctions.GetFormGroups(GlobalVariables.networkstuff, GlobalVariables.testAuth);
```

In my view I have a working DropDownListFor:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.formGroups, Model.formGroups.Select(d => new SelectListItem { Text = d.Description, Value = d.ID}), new { @id = "ddlFormGroups", @class = "form-control" })
```

but I cannot work out how to set the selected value to model.cookieValues.formSelected

How can I do this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your property `formGroups` is a collection of complex objects (`List<SIMSClient.FormGroup>`) - you cant bind a dropdown to collection (a `<select>` binds to and post back a single value). Your model needs a property to bind to, for example

```
public int SelectedID { get; set; } // assumes the ID property of FormGroup is int
```

Then in the view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedID, Model.formGroups.Select(d => new SelectListItem ....)
```

If the value of `SelectedID` matches one of the `ID` values of `FormGroup`, then that option will be selected in the view when the page is first rendered. When you post back, the value of `SelectedID` will be the value of the selected option.

Answer (score 1):

When you make the mapping to `SelectListItem` you have to set property `Selected` to `true`.

Assuming that your `model.cookieValues.formSelected` keeps the `ID` of the group , you can test if any item from array meets the condition `model.cookieValues.formSelected == group.ID`.

```
 @{ 
      groups = Model.formGroups.Select(d => 
               new SelectListItem 
               {
                  Text = d.Description, 
                  Value = d.ID,
                  Selected = (model.cookieValues.formSelected == d.ID)
               }); 
 }

@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.GroupId , groups, new { @id = "ddlFormGroups", @class = "form-control" })
```

Please notice that on your `DropDownListFor` you have `x => x.formGroups` this is wrong because it's a **list of groups**. You need to have a property where the **selected Id**(value) to be bonded.

Example having a property named `GroupId`, you can make it `string` (because `SelectListItem` property `Value` is string) and convert it on server as you want.

Comment: Many thanks - have followed your code exactly. When I debug I can see "Selected = true" on the correct value, but when it renders the html, nothing is marked as "selected"... Weird.

Comment: @TrevorDaniel Have you tried an Ctrl+F5 maybe your browser don't make use of the new changes? sometimes happens to me

Comment: ctrl+f5 made no difference. neither did changing browser to Chrome and Firefox... I don't understand as the value of the correct listitem is definitely true

Comment: @TrevorDaniel you are binding the Id of the selected item to the wrong property from model, please see the update.